# React Native Set TextInput Value Uppercase

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new in React Native and not sure why it shows unexpected result. If I type 'a' then 'a' it shows 'AAA', and so on.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      userName: ''
    }
  }

  formatUserName = (textValue) => {
    // If I remove toUpperCase() below, it shows expected result.
    this.setState({ userName: textValue.toUpperCase() });
  }

  render() {
    ...
    <TextInput
      onChangeText={textValue => this.formatUserName(textValue)}
      value={this.state.userName} />
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I also had the same problem. In iOS it works perfectly but there's a problem only in android.

This one small hack seemed to work for me:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      userName: ''
    }
  }

  formatUserName = (textValue) => {
    this.setState({ userName: textValue.toUpperCase() });
  }

  render() {
    ...
    <TextInput
      onChangeText={textValue => this.formatUserName(textValue)}
      keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'default' : 'visible-password'}
      value={this.state.userName} />
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 32):

If you want to change input string to uppercase string, then you can use **autoCapitalize** props in TextInput.

```
<TextInput
  autoCapitalize = {"characters"}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ userName: text })}
  value={this.state.userName} />
```

Props **autoCapitalize** has following options:

- characters: all characters.
- words: first letter of each word.
- sentences: first letter of each sentence (default).
- none: don't auto capitalize anything.

Default value is **sentences**

Comment: I tried this method but doesn't work in my case. Nothing happened on typing. Already restart metro and rerun `run-android`. Tested on Android Emulator Pixel 2 API 29. Any suggestions? I would love to use this proper method.

Comment: It worked in mine! Expo 44 and running it bare metal on Android 12 (S10e).  Id did add a `toUppercase` after hitting submit, as it will give me 100% correct formatting.